Is cyanomethanide more stable than 2‐oxoethanide?

Which carbanion is more stable?
$$\underset{(\textbf{a})}{\ce{H2\overset{-}{C}-CN}} \qquad \underset{(\textbf{b})}{\ce{H_2\overset{-}{C}-CHO}}$$

If we talk about the −M effect, $\ce{CN}$ is higher than the $\ce{CHO}$ group in the −M group order. With this logic carbanion (a) should be more stable.
But at the same time, oxygen atom is more electronegative than the nitrogen atom. Based on this the carbanion (b) should be more stable.

Go with the second paragraph

Compare the pKa values  ~25 for acetonitrile, ~13.5 for acetaldehyde

a is more stable than b because -I effect of CN is more than CHO group.
Either consider mesomeric effect or consider inductive effect answer will be same from both ways.
